# Conditional Form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a form where certain fields should only show depending on the initial product selected, here's the JS i have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#product").change(function() {
            var selected = $("#product option:selected").text();
            $('div').hide();
            $('#' + selected).show();

        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div').hide();
        });
    }); //]]>
</script>
```

and here is the HTML so far:

```
<select id="product">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="1">Options that are available for Product 1</div>
<div id="2">Options that are available for Product 2</div>
<div id="3">Options that are available for Product 3</div>
<div id="4">Options that are available for Product 4</div>
<div id="5">Options that are available for Product 5</div>
<div id="6">Options that are available for Product 6</div>
<div id="7">Options that are available for Product 7</div>
```

The problem i'm having is that in the options (1/2/3/4/5/6/7) these need to be product names, but it doesnt work without the numbers in there. So for example 1 should be called Product 1, 2 should be called Product 2, and so forth.

Can you help?

Comment: its working check it again.

Comment: @SatishSharma he wants it to show `Product 1, Product 2, ...` instead of `1,2,...`

Comment: then use the select box value var selected = $("#product").val();

Answer (score 3):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3T3S/)

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#product").change(function () {
         var selected = $("#product option:selected").val();
         $('div').hide();
         $('#' + selected).show();

     });
     $('div').hide();
 });
```

**Description**

By using `.val()` instead of `.text()` you will be getting the option's value.  This let's you show the user anything like `Screwdriver` instead of `Product 1`.

The removal of the following code is because it is duplicate of `$(document).ready(function () {`:

`$(window).load(function() {`

Although the functionality differs in this situation there isn't a benefit of both usages.

---

**HTML**

```
<select id="product">
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
    <option value="4">Product 4</option>
    <option value="5">Product 5</option>
    <option value="6">Product 6</option>
    <option value="7">Product 7</option>
</select>
<div id="1">Options that are available for Product 1</div>
<div id="2">Options that are available for Product 2</div>
<div id="3">Options that are available for Product 3</div>
<div id="4">Options that are available for Product 4</div>
<div id="5">Options that are available for Product 5</div>
<div id="6">Options that are available for Product 6</div>
<div id="7">Options that are available for Product 7</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected= $("#product option:selected").val();
```

Try it please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.text()`

```
 var selected = $("#product").val();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLCK6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
var selected = $("#product option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is doing the following:

1. Create a container `div` for all of the different product-related forms
2. Listen for change events on the select box
3. When a select event is caught, hide all of the children in the container `div` and then show the one that has been selected.

I also suggest that you decouple the product form configuration from the value of the select box, so that you have greater freedom as far as controlling your form.

---

**A working example** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAq8r/))

HTML

```
<body>
    <select id="selector">
        <option data-for="p1-form">Product 1</option>
        <option data-for="p2-form">Product 2</option>
        <option data-for="p3-form">Product 3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="product-forms">
        <div id="p1-form" class="product-form">
            Product 1 form
        </div>
        <div id="p2-form" class="product-form">
            Product 2 form
        </div>
        <div id="p3-form" class="product-form">
            Product 3 form
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.product-form {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var $selector = $('#selector');
var $productForms = $('#product-forms');
$selector.change(function () {
    var toEnable = $('option:selected', $selector).data('for');
    $productForms.children().css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + toEnable).css('display', 'block');
}).change();
```